# Is it possible to make player progress bar in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make progress bar in React Native.
I want to use 'react-native-sound-player' and 'react-native-community/slider' libraries.

I just make some function like back to before 10 seconds, and forward to 10 seconds.
But, I can't present current time in slider.

I want to show current time in slider like normal player.
But I didn't know how to do.

**And I have a question. The react-native-sound-player provides getInfo() function. This function return currentTime and duration in 'Promise type'. Is it possible to make real time progress bar using this function?**

And I'm beginner in React Native so please help me..

Additional information is below.

1. I'm using react native 0.68.4 version
2. this app will be worked on android and ios

I want to progress bar working in real time based.
Like normal player.

Comment: You can use currentTime provided by library itself check this [link](https://github.com/johnsonsu/react-native-sound-player#getinfo--promisecurrenttime-number-duration-number)

Comment: Thank you for replaying!
I already know and I'm using this function. But I want to know the way how to using that function in realtime. 
I didn't know how to move the point in slider as time goes by. Please let me know the way..